# Why does DELETE not work after an UPDATE in a CTE?

Tags: postgresql, cte, dml

```
CREATE table test (
    id integer,
    x integer
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 1);
```

`SELECT` works:

```
WITH res AS (
    UPDATE test SET x = 10 WHERE id = 1
    RETURNING id
)
SELECT id FROM test WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM res);

id 
---
 1
(1 row)
```

But `DELETE` does not work:

```
WITH res AS (
    UPDATE test SET x = 10 WHERE id = 1
    RETURNING id
)
DELETE FROM test WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM res);

DELETE 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Common table expressions (CTE)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) of the same statement are *all* based on the same snapshot of the database. I.e. all sub-statements see the same state of underlying tables.

Your `DELETE` tries to modify the **same row(s)** that your `UPDATE` already modifies.
[The manual addresses your case ***exactly***:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

> Trying to update the same row twice in a single statement is not
>   supported. Only one of the modifications takes place, but it is not
>   easy (and sometimes not possible) to reliably predict which one. **This
>   also applies to deleting a row that was already updated in the same
>   statement: only the update is performed.** Therefore you should
>   generally avoid trying to modify a single row twice in a single
>   statement. In particular avoid writing `WITH` sub-statements that could
>   affect the same rows changed by the main statement or a sibling
>   sub-statement. The effects of such a statement will not be
>   predictable.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read the documentation.